# Send JSON data when order created event from platform A to Postman flow by webhook URL

Tags: postman, integration, webhooks

I want to catch order created event from  by deploy Postman flow and copy the webhook URL to paste it in (platform A) then when order created send JSON data to postman flow and edit it then send it to (platform B) by post API method

[image]

I catch JSON data but I couldn't edit it to send it to the other platform.

Please, what the next block or collection I should use?